# How to import a function from a typescript file into next.config.mjs?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm working on a Next.js project in typescript. I have a helper function in a file called `utils.mts` that I'd like to use in the `next.config.mjs` file to setup a custom webpack loader.

When I import the function from the file, I get an error that says the file type is unknown. I have tried changing the extension to `.ts` but that did not help either.

Is there a way for me to import that function written in typescript into the `next.config.mjs` file?

Comment: Simple really, you can't. You would need to compile it down to javascript first.

Comment: Ah okay. I've restructured my project to remove any dependency on next.config.mjs and use it directly in the project.